# Mudar estilo da janela Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Como faço para mudar o estilo da minha janela para um RibbonForm. Sendo que em questão de cores já está tranquilo. Veja a imagem:

[image: A Janela do aplicativo ficou assim!]

E agora como utilizo o método `CreateParams` para mudar o título e centralizá-lo e criar um efeito glow em um Label?

Comment: tipo ficou com algumas falhas mas isso é o de menos.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para adicionar novas informações, como a do comentário acima. Se quiser conhecer um pouco mais das funcionalidades, recomendo um passeio pelo [tour] e uma vista na [help]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utilize a dll `System.Windows.Forms.Ribbon35.dll`

e na inicialização:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ribbon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Ribbon();
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.Controls.Add(ribbon1);
}
private System.Windows.Forms.Ribbon ribbon1;
```

Mais detalhes pode ser observado em:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application-Cs

Comment: ah sim conheço.

Comment: e tem uma esse Form é um System.Windows.Forms padrão

Comment: Mas o problema em usar o System.Windows.Forms.Ribbon.35 não funciona no **OrbStyle=2007**